# Testing the hypothesis of a specific effect size (eg. correlation between .3 and .8)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, effect-size

I am wondering how to test the hypothesis of a specific effect size (e.g., "There is a correlation between .30 and .50"). Of course, the null hypothesis would be that there is a correlation below .30 or above .50.

Let's say I found a correlation of .60 with a 95% confidence interval of .45 and .75. How would that be interpreted in relation to the hypothesis. Something tells me that it is just not enough for the confidence interval to "extend" into the "desired" interval.

How would you generally approach this or do you know any literature on the subject? I am working with R.

Comment: Could you use a confidence interval? Or look into [tag:equivalence] testing.

Comment: I think ---  Whether you consider the null hypothesis to be that 1. The correlation is between 0.30 and 0.50, or 2. The correlation is either < 0.30 or > 0.50:  In either case, having an overlapping confidence interval as in your example would not give you enough evidence to reject that null hypothesis.

Comment: One wonders how scientifically meaningful a hypothesis like "the correlation is less than 0.30 or greater than 0.50" might possibly be.  Aren't you perhaps in a position where you just need to *estimate* an effect size, along with some assessment of its precision (like a standard error, margin of error, or confidence interval)?

Comment: @whuber asks about the meaning of the hypothesis: in this case, I actually assume a medium effect or explicitly no small and no large effect for theoretical considerations. Of course, I could also "only" explore the effect, but that would not be meaningful enough with regard to the test of two complementary theories.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the comments. I think that equivalence testing as suggested by @kjetil b halvorsen might be the right approach. The procedure would allow me to specify a range within which I assume the effect to occur. In R it could by done with the plugin [TOSTER](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TOSTER/vignettes/IntroductionToTOSTER.html). This is (if I understand correctly) also in line with @sal Mangiafico's approach.